# WPF - Creating a Parabola in a square using animations

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to develop a WPF program to draw a Parabola using animations. I haven't even started with the animations yet, but I can not manage to draw the parabola properly with the lines.

I have created a grid in the mainwindow and basically the issue here is that I can't manage to get the lines appearing properly when I create them.

```
protected double midaCanva;
    protected int numCantonades;
    protected bool isTopLeft;
    protected bool isTopRight;
    protected bool isBottomLeft;
    protected bool isBottomRight;
    protected bool isHalf;
    protected double lineQty;
    protected bool isAllLines;
    protected int lineTime;
    protected Brush lineColor;
    private List<Shape> llistaLinies;       

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        midaCanva = cnv_dibuix.Height;
        lineQty = (double)iud_linies.Value;
        llistaLinies = new List<Shape>();
        CrearLinies(lineQty, midaCanva);
        Dibuixar(llistaLinies);

        //lineColor = clr_linies.SelectedColor;
    }        

    private List<Shape> CrearLinies(double numeroLinies, double midaCanvas)
    {
        llistaLinies = new List<Shape>();
        double divisions = midaCanva / lineQty;
        double divisio = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineQty; i++)
        {
            Line linia = new Line();
            linia.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            linia.X1 = 0;                
            linia.Y1 = midaCanvas - divisio;
            linia.X2 = divisio + divisions;
            linia.Y2 = 0;
            linia.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            linia.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            linia.StrokeThickness = 1;
            llistaLinies.Add(linia);
            divisio += divisions;
        }
        return llistaLinies;
    }

    private void Dibuixar(List<Shape> linies)
    {
        cnv_dibuix.Children.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < lineQty; i++)
        {
            Line linia = (Line)linies[i];
            linia.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            Canvas.SetLeft(linia, 0);
            Canvas.SetBottom(linia, 0);
            cnv_dibuix.Children.Add(linia);
        }
    }
```

The part where I set the lines X1, X2, Y1, Y2 must be wrong. It should appear like this:

[image]

I'm getting very weird results, such as this:

[image]

Here you can find the .xaml:

> [Design Code](https://codeshare.io/5wE9kR)

Should I do it differently? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: did you mean [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) instead of  [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)?

Comment: Why do you call Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetBottom there in your _Dibuixar_ method?. Explain what those method calls do. No, stop. Don't just explain your assumptions about what they do. Rather, read the documentation for both `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Bottom` attached properties (Canvas.SetLeft/Bottom are the "setters" for those attached properties). Based on what is written **precisely** in the documentation, try to explain to yourself what `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Bottom` do and how it affects the rendering  / placement of the lines on the canvas.

Comment: Side note: The origin - or zero coordinate (0,0) - of the canvas is its upper left corner. According to the logic of calculating the line point coordinates in your _CrearLinies_ method, the hyperbola would be flipped vertically in comparison to the image you have shown in your question.

Comment: Hi @elgonzo. It was all about those properties. Thank you. I should have read the documentation properly.Thank you again.